# Data Factory - Cannot connect to SQL Database only when triggered from Blob

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Also on the Microsoft Docs site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/514135/data-factory-sqlfailedtoconnect-when-triggered-fro.html)

I have a data factory pipeline that should use a Copy Data activity to insert rows from a CSV file of a blob into Azure Sql.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I run the pipeline by clicking the "Debug" button in the designer window then it all works great. However, if I trigger the pipeline by copying the sample CSV to the blob container then I get the following error:

> ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
> connect to SQL Database: '', Database: '', User: ''. Check the linked
> service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database
> firewall allows the integration runtime to access

I have checked that the target sql server database has the option checked to "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server".

Any ideas gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was missing a connection string value from the "Override template parameters" section of the release pipeline.

[image]

This meant that after deployment, the linked service did not have a connection string.

The key to Understanding this was learning of the "Switch to live mode" button from the data factory pipeline editor view:

[image]

After clicking this, I was able to browse the status of the linked service as were - rather than as per "development" mode.